# recursive method that compares all elements in array and returns index

Tags: java, arrays, recursion, methods

I'm trying to create recursive method that returns index of the element that's equal to X.
We have some array, and a number X. I need to compare X with all numbers in the array and return index of the number which is equal to X.

Here is my trial:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    final List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
            {
                add(3);
                add(4);
                add(6);
                add(1);
                add(9);
            }
        };

        final int x = 3;
    }
```

Comment: What is the actual question?

Comment: This method is never called in your code, so I dunno what you are expecting for output

Comment: @rabbitguy I'm expecting index number. I have in array number 3 (which is first), and if my x is 3, then i should get 0. Shall I use indexOf method to achieve that?

Comment: Your findSame method is never called, so no mater what you do in that method, your output will always be the same

Comment: Your question only contains requirements - it is not showing any efforts from your side to solve this problem yourself. Please add your attempts to this questions - as this site is not a free "we do your (home)work" service. Beyond that: please turn to the [help] to learn how/what to ask here. Thanks!

Comment: *OR*: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: @GhostCat I've removed my trial as it was confusing people. I think most of people understood my question, so chill.

Comment: Well - by doing so you created exactly that impression: that you only have the assignment there, and no efforts of your own to solve that problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is some editing in your code.
it can be written in much more simple way, without using ArrayList.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
class RecursionForSearching {

```
static List<Integer> numbers;

public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>() {
        {
            add(3);
            add(4);
            add(6);
            add(1);
            add(9);
        }

    };
    int x = 1;
    int result = searchNum(x, 0);
    if (result != -1) {
        System.out.println("There is x in the array, and the index is: " + result);
        System.out.println("There is x in the array, and the Position is: " + (result + 1));
    } else
        System.out.println("X is not found in List");
}

private static int searchNum(int x, Integer index) {

    if (index == numbers.size())
        return -1;
    if (!(numbers.get(index) == x)) {
        return searchNum(x, index + 1);
    }

    return index;
}
```

}

Comment: It's great!! Thank you! @UrvashiSoni

Comment: @Camila- My Pleasure!
If this works fine, Please accept it as answer.
You can also upvote it.

Comment: @NeilLocketz whats wrong with the way she is making an arraylist? i initialize them like that all the time.

Comment: oh yes. i'm very aware, and that arrayList is initialized correctly.

Comment: @UrvashiSoni Hi, one more thing if you know, if i was to test with junit this method, would that be something like this:

 public void searchNumReturnsIndex(){
  CS102DZ14 dz = new CS102DZ14();
        System.out.println("X in the array ");
        
        int x = 1;
        Integer index = 0;
        int expResult = 3;
        int result = dz.searchNum(x, 0);
        assertEquals(expResult, result);  
 }

Comment: @NeilLocketz Just try it yourself. It works - this code creates an **anonymous inner class** that extends ArrayList, and then runs a non-static initializer block that calls the add method of the list. I can't make up my mind if that is crazy or create. But in any case it is something that probably neither the OP nor the person writing it down really understand.

Comment: Hint: your way of declaring that list ... works ... but is extremely unusual. Simply go for `Arrays.asList(1,2,3,4)`; Done.

Answer (score 2):

So `findSmallest` returns the smallest element. What if we stop when we find the element you are looking for?

Like this:

```
private static final int findSame(Iterator<Integer> iterator, Integer x, int idx) {
    if (!iterator.hasNext()) {
        // Don't have a next! return -1
        return -1;
    }

    if (iterator.next().equals(x)) {
        // Found it!
        // Let's give back the current index.
        return idx;
    } else {
        // Not here, lets check the rest.
        return findSame(iterator, x, idx+1);
    }
}
```

So you just call it the first time with `idx` 0.

You're going to run into other problems since you aren't using valid syntax.

Code in main should be:

```
final List<Integer> numbers = Arrays.asList(3, 4, 6, 1, 9);
final Integer x = Integer.valueOf(3);
System.out.println(findSame(numbers.iterator(), x, 0));
```

Comment: Sorry, I think I didn't explain my question well. I'm not looking for a smallest number. I'm searching for equal number to X, from an array above. If there is one, then print the index, if if not print 0;

Comment: @Camila Right, this does that. (it returns -1 in the case it didn't find it since 0 could be the first index)

Comment: How do I call to check it?

Comment: I just saw that you started with a `findSmallest` and tried to build off of that.

Comment: `findSame(numbers.iterator(), x, 0)`

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to do that, there is very ***VERY*** simple code for it. Trust me. Here's the breakdown in Java code:

```
private static int FindIt(int[] arr, boolean it, int index, int want)
{
    //want is the wanted number
    //The integer index should be set at 0 in the beginning. It is the index of the array
    //The boolean it represents if we find it. 
    //The base case
    if (it){
    return index;
    }
    else if (index == arr.length){
    //The usual not found factor
    return -1;
    }
    else{
    //Advance it if you don't find it
        if (arr[index] == want){
                return index;
        }
        else{
        return FindIt(arr, it, index+1);
        }
    }
}
```

That's actually all you have to do. I hope it helps!

Comment: You're missing something very important. `it` will always be the same as passed in, so it always returns 0 (if you call it with 0 start) or -1

Comment: I thought I missed something. Then I realized that I wasn't even doing it properly. Thanks for reminding me, @Neil Locketz